# How to make file clickable in upload collection?

Tags: sapui5

I am doing upload collection component in sap ui5. I want to make file clickable after upload. Previously uploaded files are getting clickable but currently uploaded files are not getting clickable. Please help me to find solution.

Below is my XML code :

Comment: Can you share some code to provide a better understanding of your problem ?

Comment: I want event which fire after clicking on uploaded file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not set the mode for the Upload list, by default this is set to None. Add a mode parameter in you List as below. This will make the List clickable.

```
mode="SingleSelectMaster"
```

Reference: 
https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.UploadCollection.html#getMode
https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.ListMode.html